# Measure to calculate Average Unit Cost providing unexpected values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'd like to show the average unit cost in each year for a series of items I'm purchasing. I'll be purchasing 13 items over 10 years. In some years, I purchase multiple items, in others, I purchase only one.

My Measure is Sum(Cost)/DistinctCount(Items). In all cases, this results in a count of 13 items, rather than the number of items in a given year. For reference, I'm using this in a line chart, where years are along the x-axis, so I (wrongly) assumed that the Year context would apply. Any suggestions?

For example, in one year, I'm purchasing 5 items for $350 dollars, which should result in an average unit cost of $70, but is instead returning $26.92, which is 350/13.

Comment: Too many unknown factors. Without a dummy tables and result sample it's hard to give a correct answer. As Gaziz said the issue seems to be about your data model.

Answer (score 1):

If the year context doesn't apply, then it sounds like an issue with your data model. Have a look at whether there's a relationship from your Date table to your Fact table (the one with the item counts).